# Stop Tkinter freezing When using Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I know this type of question asked many times but they are not simple as I can understand. So here I'm doing this:

```
for location in unique_location:
    chrome_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_location, args=(link_code, location_code, location.upper()), name='locationthread', daemon=True)
    chrome_thread.start()
    chrome_thread.join()
```

But it freezes the Tkinter window and I don't how to wait to complete for this but not let it freeze the window.
Please help me if is there any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit :
I figured it how to do it but it will run so many threads which bad idea

```
first_thread = chrome_threads[0].start()
chrome_threads[0].join()

if len(chrome_threads) > 1:
    newthreads = []
    for i in range(1, len(chrome_threads[1:])):
        chrome_threads[i].start()
        newthreads.append(chrome_threads[i])
        totalcon += 1
        if totalcon == 2:
            totalcon = 0
            for i in newthreads:
                i.join()
            newthreads = []
        else:
            for i in newthreads:
                i.join()
            newthreads = []
```

I have this code here I'm running only the first thread for the first time, after completing this run 2 threads then wait then again run 2 threads, if there is only one under `else` then just run and it will finish. Is that a nice way?
I know there are so many ways one of them would be a queue way but I don't know how it works as I find my way easy for me.

Comment: with `join` you wait till the thread is done. How to share state between threads can be easily googled and the best way depends on your needs. Please do some reasearch on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

with multithreading the `join()` function will wait for the thread to finish. this is what is causing your program to freeze

you can use `thread.is_alive()` to check whether you should join.

for example:

```py
for location in unique_location:
    chrome_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_location, args=(link_code, location_code, location.upper()), name='locationthread', daemon=True)
    chrome_thread.start()
    chrome_thread.join()

... store chrome_thread somewhere
```

then in your main gui loop

```py
while True:
    if not _STORED_THREAD.is_alive() then _STORED_THREAD.join()
```

Comment: Can you help me with the edited question?

Comment: @AdarshRaj please do not ask multiple questions in the same post. If you have a new question, create a new post. Also avoid asking opinion based posts and/or "please help me" posts